# Sharepoint 2013 workflow not firing when document checked in but works if checked out

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

We have a document library that has both Document sets and Documents. We also have a Workflow that is manually started by the user on any item in this library. The problem we are having is that the workflow doesn't start if the document is checked in and . If the document is checked out, it works fine. The workflow runs fine on a Document Set.

Looking into the log files, I see the following messages:

Skip lookup field SortBehavior as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe 
Skip lookup field CheckedOutUserId as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID 46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe 
Skip lookup field SyncClientId as it's not dependent lookup, but it has PrimaryFieldId ID   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe
The target list of field Taxonomy Catch All Column, TaxCatchAll, does not exists in the current web or the current user does not have permissioin to see it. Skip it.   46fff461-81e3-b73a-9fba-f4f1e8088cbe

Immediately below these lines, I see the following message: 
The file "http://sharepointurl.com/abc/TestWf/select_element.pdf" is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes......

The workflow is very simple and only logs a test message. I am not sure why SharePoint is trying to check-out the document but I have a feeling that it has something to do with the above messages.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks